# Java Regex Capture Text Between """ or '''

Tags: java, regex

I have a document I am trying to parse with Java Regex and in it appears text in quotes either """  or ''' so you have:

""" Bla, you're not very nice! """ 
or:

''' Bla, this 1 isn't a great example '''

I have been trying along the lines of `["""|''']([\p{Alnum}|\p{Blank}]+)[\"""|''']`

Assumptions:
The text will start and end with either """ or '''
The  text could include numbers, letter, blanks and punctuation
The body of the text will not include the sequence of three " or three '

Comment: You need to use `("""|''')` instead of `["""|''']` for a start. `[]` is a character class not a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern: `("""|''').*?\1`

Given:

```
"""Hello, World!""" some unquoted text """ lorem ipsum ''" dolor """ some more unquoted text '''single quotes'''
''' Bla, this 1 isn't a great example '''
```

It will match:

1. `"""Hello, World!"""`
2. `""" lorem ipsum ''" dolor """`
3. `'''single quotes'''`
4. `''' Bla, this 1 isn't a great example '''`

You can also probably be more specific than `.*?` but I wasn't sure what characters you meant by "punctuation".

Comment: This is not according to OPs specifications: `The body of the text will not include the sequence of three " or three '`

Comment: OK, so take the ''' out of the second example then... What's the difference? If it really is supposed to match quotes that are mismatched then you can replace `\1` with `('''|""")` but I doubt that is the case.

Comment: Yes, I changed my comment since this isn't wrong, just confusing with the examples.

Comment: Fair enough, I updated the example to contain `''"` instead to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Something like so worked for me:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"{3}(.*?)\"{3})|('{3}(.*?)'{3})");
        String s1 = "\"\"\" Bla, you're not very nice! \"\"\"";
        String s2 = "''' Bla, this 1 isn't a great example '''";

        Matcher m1 = p.matcher(s1);
        Matcher m2 = p.matcher(s2);

        if (m1.matches())
        {
            System.out.println(m1.group(2));
        }


        if (m2.matches())
        {               
            System.out.println(m2.group(4));
        }
```

It would, however, make it simpler to just use 2 regular expressions. The above code yielded the following:

> Bla, you're not very nice!
>
> Bla, this 1 isn't a great example

One of the issues with your regular expression is that any text within the square brackets is *OR'D*, meaning that the Pipe character is useless (as an `OR` operator). You will need to replace your square brackets with round ones.

Comment: It is *not* useless. A `|` inside a character class will match a literal `|` in the source text. Repeating characters inside the class, on the other hand, most certainly is useless. It is moot anyway, since the actual problem is that it is supposed to be a group.

Comment: @veredesmarald: Yeah you do have a point. I have modified my answer slightly.